# aggs filter is not working in elastic searach

Tags: elasticsearch

I am working On Elastic Search For My Current Project.. Need to Remove Duplicate Records My O/p Is as follows:

> array
>   (

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [_index] => vendors
        [_type] => practiceareas
        [_id] => 582
        [_score] => 
        [_source] => Array
            (
                [practice_area_id] => 364
                [id] => 582
                [practice_area_name] => Joint Pains
                [industry_id] => 9
                [category_id] => 12
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [_index] => vendors
        [_type] => practiceareas
        [_id] => 1315
        [_score] => 
        [_source] => Array
            (
                [practice_area_id] => 237
                [id] => 1315
                [practice_area_name] => Anemia
                [industry_id] => 9
                [category_id] => 15
            )
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [_index] => vendors
        [_type] => practiceareas
        [_id] => 2087
        [_score] => 
        [_source] => Array
            (
                [practice_area_id] => 364
                [id] => 2087
                [practice_area_name] => Joint Pains
                [industry_id] => 2
                [category_id] => 12
            )
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [_index] => vendors
        [_type] => practiceareas
        [_id] => 2820
        [_score] => 
        [_source] => Array
            (
                [practice_area_id] => 237
                [id] => 2820
                [practice_area_name] => Anemia
                [industry_id] => 2
                [category_id] => 15
            )
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [_index] => vendors
        [_type] => practiceareas
        [_id] => 5312
        [_score] => 
        [_source] => Array
            (
                [practice_area_id] => 364
                [id] => 5312
                [practice_area_name] => Joint Pains
                [industry_id] => 2
                [category_id] => 28
            )
    )
```

)

I need to eliminate replicate values by using practice_area_id / practice_area_name

I already tired as per references.. and my code is as follows:

```
$query = array(
            "from" => $from,
            "size" => $size,
            "sort" => array(array($fieldname => 'desc')),
            "query" => array(
                "filtered" => array(
                    "query" => array("match_all" => array())
                )
            ),
            "aggs" => array(
                "distinct" => array(
                    "terms" => array(
                        "field" => "practice_area_name",
                    )
                )
            )
        );
```

But it is not working.. please help me with a solution. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What happens if you use `practice_area_id` instead of `practice_area_name` in your aggregation?

Comment: I already tried by.. practice_area_id.. but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

you want to remove replicate documents or you just want to check total distinct documents by practice_area_name or practice_area_id ?

> For the second question the sense query look like this

```
POST vendors/practiceareas/_search
{
    "size": 0, 
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "aggs":{
        "distinct-values":{
            "terms":{
                "field":"practice_area_id",
                "min_doc_count":2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> output look like this

```
"aggregations": {
      "distinct-values": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": 364,
               "doc_count": 3
            },
            {
               "key": 237,
               "doc_count": 2
            }
         ]
      }
}
```

Comment: I tired as above.. like you said, but it is not working for me @Vishal

Comment: hi vishal, getting same response as you said.. but i am getting 10 records only.. but i have so many records.. and also i need some other info with id (key).. please let me know.. what i do ??

Comment: if you are talking about aggregation then, here in my above example i have 5 records but all of them have **practice_area_id** common so it will distribute as per the **key**. you are getting only ten responses but did you see how may **doc_count** each bucket has? kindly update your question with the response which you are getting so that i may help you further. and what do you mean by other info with id?